# iOS: Launch App via universal link makes app crash

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-universal-links

I am using Flutter to develop iOS app. When I launch the app via universal link (e.g. enter the url in Safari and click the OPEN button ), the app launches but will crash immediately. But if the app is already running on background, when I click the link, it will not crash. When it crashes, I got the following log. So I commented out all the code related to NSUserActivity, but I still got the same error.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSUserActivity)'
```

Any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: I can't clearly understand the crash may be considered positing the complete crash stack shown in Xcode Console.

Comment: This is IMO the only meaningful log so I didn't post other logs. But I've solved my probelm. Thanks anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the probelm, the bug is due to the failure of JSON conversion in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function. I had a JSON conversion in one of my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions methods(serveral flutter plugins call override this method). When enter the app via UL, a NSDictionary will be carried to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. For instance, if enter from Safari, this NSDictionary will look like

```
dict :{
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey = "com.apple.mobilesafari";
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey =     {
        UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityIdentifierKey = "ABCD-SOME-KEY";
        UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityKey = "<NSUserActivity: 0x12345678>";
        UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityTypeKey = NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb;
    };
}
```

So when converting it to JSON, I  get " uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (NSUserActivity)' ".
I think what confused me is that from the log I thought the term "NSUserActivity" is something in my code (Since I do use this object in continueUserActivity method, and I had modified continueUserActivity to solve this problem before I got this bug), so I commented out these code but not wokring. However, I didn't notice it is a term inside a dictionary which could be created at runtime.
My solution is to check the key in the dictionary before Json conversion and add try catch to avoid this bug.